# Unable to cancel infinite Tkinter (nested) after loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, infinite-loop, cancellation

**TL;DR:** I've got an `after` loop in Tkinter that I want to run indefinitely, but want to be able to kill if I want to restart the loop with new starting inputs. As each iteration of the loop calls the `after` function again, I can't work out how to get the correct after ID to the `after_cancel` function to kill the old loop when launching the new one.

**More detailed post:**
So I'm trying to produce a (dot matrix) scrolling text bar via Tkinter for use in a virtual departure board. For this to work I need a given bit of text to scroll across the relevant part of the GUI indefinitely until an updated bit of text is ready to replace it. I've managed the scrolling indefinitely part just fine; however I'm having an issue stopping the old scroll ready for the new scroll to take it's place.

I feel like my problem is that once one of those loops gets going I can't easily 'communicate' with it; nor can my new loop 'tell' my old one to stop. In attempts to resolve this I tried having a couple toggle attributes within the GUI object, but these attempts failed (not to say it's not possible this way; just that I couldn't manage it). Further searching for a solution has lead to me feeling like the Tkinter function `after_cancel` is the likely solution, but I've been unable to implement this as the way I loop the text involves using the `after` function of Tkinter again (thus the after ID is constantly changing for the loop). I can't work this one out, and if I'm honest I'm unsure if it's me not fully getting the `after` and/or `after_cancel` functions, or if it's more that I'm looping my function in a poor way (i.e. whether I shouldn't be using the `after` function to achieve this).

Any help/advice would be much appreciated; and I'm more than happy any additional information if required.

**Below is my minimum, reproducible example code**. I've quickly put this together and it is very much like a simpler version of my main code (here I'm moving a square rather than text on an dot matrix display); this loops the functions in the same way as my real code, and has the same problem within it.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.background = "black"
        self.width = 600
        self.height = 150

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.width, height=self.height, borderwidth=0, \
                                highlightthickness=0, background = self.background)

        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")

        self.run_id_1 = self.after( 100, lambda: self.moving_square( "red", 50, 10 ) )

        self.run_id_2 = self.after( 5000, lambda: self.moving_square( "green", 200, 90, \
                                                                      prev_run_id = self.run_id_1 ) )

    def moving_square( self, color, x_top_left, y_top_left, last_square = None, prev_run_id = None ):

        if not prev_run_id == None:
            self.after_cancel( prev_run_id )

        if not last_square == None:
            self.canvas.delete( last_square )

        last_square = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x_top_left, y_top_left, x_top_left + 50, \
                                                   y_top_left + 50, outline=color, fill=color)

        if x_top_left + 50 < 0:
            self.after( 500, lambda: self.moving_square( color, self.width, y_top_left, last_square ) )
        else:
            self.after( 500, lambda: self.moving_square( color, x_top_left - 10, y_top_left, last_square ) )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App( )
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, You don't need to use `lambda` with after. You can so `self.after(500, self.moving_square, color, self.width, y_top_left, last_square)`. It becomes a bit easier to read without `lambda`.

Comment: Every time you call `after()`, assign the ID value it returns to `self.run_id_1` or `self.run_id_2` so you can call `after_cancel()` if needed.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for the help :) My only issue when trying to move towards avoiding lambda here is having two optional arguments. If I wanted to say only provide the second of these, with lambda I can put something like "prev_run_id = "SPAM" and ignore the preceding optional arg. However, when moving to the non-lambda way of doing it I can't do this; is there any way to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call the function again, you need to update that ID so that — as you suspected — you have a reference you can pass to `after_cancel`. You already store that reference as `self.run_id_1`, but you don't update one.

The simplest way to do it would be to add a check `if color == 'red'` then set `self.run_id_1 = self.after(...)`, and likewise for `'green'` and `self.run_id_2`.

However, I should note that the structure of your `moving_square` function is not ideal. One reason you might have found it hard to locate what to change is that it's already overly parametrized. You should either divide its work up a little, splitting into various functions that are more specific. Or you could create a table of data to store the relevant states and ids of the scrolling rows so you can streamline the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

I thought that was probably the issue, but I couldn't think what to put as the variable(s)/arguments(s) within the if-statement to make it so that the correct ID was updated. Based on your reply I realised I could store these in a dictionary within an object attribute; I can then parse a string which points to which ID it needs to update/use. However, you mention using a table of data? I'm unsure what you're referring to here?

I'm also unsure what you mean by overly parametrised? Do you mean I'm having to have to many function arguments in the way I've done it?

Comment: @Steve Yes and yes. By table I meant a dict, and by overly parametrized I meant too many arguments. Often when you find yourself using a "flag" argument, such as `color` where a given string determines the behaviour, it's a sign that you should either split functions or go for an object-oriented, polymorphic approach. (Otherwise you can see how with more than two colours it would get very convoluted.)

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant; thank you very much for the help in resolving my problem (using a dict to, at the very least, contain the after IDs), and also thank you for pointing out that the way I'm parsing variables to the function could (and should) be more streamlined (I'll certainly be looking to make the relevant changes on that front).

Thank you :)